# Are my expectations about React navigation correct?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, native, expo, stack-navigator

It might be my lack of understanding, but would anyone explain if my expectations are wrong about React navigation?

My app is more or less a questionnaire where one screen handles all questions. Basically it navigates to itself with a new question ID. That fetches the proper data and displays it. Working fine, but when I press back I do not go to the previous question but to the home page. I use expo and their [recommended navigation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation#react-navigation).

My expectation is when I go back from the last page in :

```
Homepage => QuestionPage(id=1) => QuestionPage(id=3)
```

I would go back to QuestionPage with id = 1, but it goes to Homepage. I use withNavigation on both pages to maintain the navigation props.

Is this expectation wrong or is this correct navigation behavior? If so, any clues what to do to get my expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve react navigation multi-page application from single page. You need to add "react-router-dom" package in your project.

```
import {
  Route as Router,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from 'react-router-dom';
```

You have to setup router for navigate page as follow.

```
<Switch>
<Router exact path="/questionpage/:handle" component={Questionpage} />
</Switch>
```

In Question page Router :

```
this.props.match.params.handle // will help to get page number
```

By using above syntax you can get page number and able to get data exact you want.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Am I correct this is for React and not usable in React-native?

Comment: Victor H if you want to use native react then you need to use different route packages which help native to understand actions. i.e. `react-navigation`. if information helpful then don't forget to up-vote.

Comment: That what I use (as said) I use react-native and react-navigation including withNavigation

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a StackNavigator and from QuestionPage on the back button you do

```
 this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

instead of

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen')}
```

it should work !

If you want to have a custom navigation on a react navigation screen, on the backAndroid I'd recommend to listen to the didFocus like this:

```
_didFocusSubscription;
  _willBlurSubscription;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._didFocusSubscription = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', payload =>
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid)
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._willBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', payload =>
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid)
    );
  }
hardwareBackPress = () => {  this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen')} }
```

A more accurate example and the documentation regarding it is here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-android-back-button-handling.html

Comment: I meant the physical back button on a device (and the rendered one), but thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was so simple. Instead of

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Question', {id=40})}
```

I had to write

```
this.props.navigation.push('Question', {id=40})}
```